# Показ страницы только аунтефицированому пользователю, без БД

Tags: ajax, json, laravel, api

Я сделал простую аунтефикацию через ajax, без middleware и встроенной авторизации laravel,
Форма обращается по api в другой проект и если данные верны возвращает code = 200 и result = ok, в ином случае выдает ошибку через модалку, **теперь вопрос**, **если данные верны мне надо чтобы перекидывало на страницу и внутри этой страницы будут другие странницы естественно**, **и как сделать так чтобы на страницу которую перекидывало и те страницы которые в ней есть, были видны только тем кто прошел эту аунтефикацию, заранее благодарю!**

```
 //Route          

         Route::get('/agentlogin', function () {
        return view('pages.agentlogin');
        })->name('login');

  Route::post('/agentlogin', [CovidController::class, 'ftLogin'])->name('ftLogin');

  //controller

         public function ftLogin(Request $request)
{
    $response = Http::withOptions(['verify' => false])->post('https:/bla.bla/bla/blabla/login', [
        "token" => "sfsdfsfs*sdffsdfsdfsdfg",
        "username" => $request->username,
        "password" => $request->password
    ])->json();

    if ($response['code'] == 200) {
        return response()->json($response);
    } else {
        return response()->json([
            'code' => 401,
            'result' => false
        ]);
    }
}

    //html form ajax

  @extends('layouts.app')

 @section('content')
<div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">Вход</div>

                <div class="card-body">
                    <form method="POST" action="" id="loginForm">
                        @csrf

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="name" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">Имя</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="username" type="text"
                                       class="form-control @error('name') is-invalid @enderror" name="username"
                                       value="{{ old('name') }}" required autocomplete="name" autofocus>

                                @error('name')
                                <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                    <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                </span>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                        </div>


                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="password" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">Пароль</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="password" type="password"
                                       class="form-control @error('password') is-invalid @enderror" name="password"
                                       required autocomplete="current-password">

                                @error('password')
                                <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                    <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                </span>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row mb-0">
                            <div class="col-md-8 offset-md-4">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                                    Войти
                                </button>

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/imask"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    function showError(text) {
        $('#modalText').html(text);
        $('#modalError').modal('show');
    }

    $('#loginForm').submit(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var username = $('#username').val();
        var password = $('#password').val();

        $.ajax({

            url: "{{route('ftLogin')}}",
            type: "post",
            data: {
                username: username,
                password: password,
                _token: '{{csrf_token()}}'

            },
            success: function (data) {
                if (data.code == 200) {
                    window.location.href = '';
                } else {
                    showError("Ошибка аунтефикации");
                }
            }
        })
    });

</script>


<div class="modal fade" id="modalError" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel"
     aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p id="modalText" style="color: crimson;"></p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


    @endsection
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как вариант, в случае успешной авторизации добавлять в сессию идентификатор успешной авторизации:

```
 if ($success) {
     $request->session()->put('authenticated', time());
     return redirect()->route('user.dashboard');
 }
```

Остается только добавить middleware для ограничения доступа к страницам:

web.php:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web', 'custom_auth']], function () {
    Route::get('/success', 'Controller@success')->name('success');
});
```

custom_auth middleware:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if (!empty(session('authenticated'))) {
        $request->session()->put('authenticated', time());
        return $next($request);
    }

    return redirect('/login');
}
```